# How to keep figure in Graphics to fixed size

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I have the following code:

```
f[u_] = Graphics[{Circle[{0, 1}, 1],  Circle[{2 Sqrt[u], u}, u]}]
Manipulate[Show[f[u]], {{u, 0.5},1,10}]
```

Now, if we try the slider, we can actually see that when we make the second circle (the one for which its center and radius depend on $u$), the first "fixed" circle (the unit circle centered in $(0,1)$) will shrink in size in the picture.

What should I do in order to keep that circle "fixed" in size, i.e. no matter how big I make the second circle, the first circle remains fixed in size when using the slider? (so the image does not zoom in/out to see both circles)

Comment: Add an appropriate fixed `PlotRange` to your `Show`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[u_] := Graphics[{Circle[{0, 1}, 1], Circle[{2 Sqrt[u], u}, u]}]
Manipulate[
 Show[
   f[u], 
   PlotRange -> PlotRange[f[10]], 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
 ],
 {{u, 0.5}, 0.5, 10}
]
```

Here I use the `PlotRange` function to extract the plot range for the graphic with the largest possible circle, i.e. the one produced by `f[10]`, then apply 5% padding to that range to make sure that everything fits comfortably.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: @QWE Glad to help! You are very welcome.